# mix deps.get fails, {:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order}}]}

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, hex-pm

I'm trying to fetch dependencies for my elixir project. I can't tell if Hex is down or not (I was able to fetch just fine this morning). When I run

```
$ mix deps.get
```

I see this:

```
    Failed to fetch record for 'hexpm/phoenix_live_reload' from registry (using cache)
{:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order}}]}
    Failed to fetch record for 'hexpm/phoenix_ecto' from registry (using cache)
{:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order}}]}
    Failed to fetch record for 'hexpm/phoenix' from registry (using cache)
{:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order}}]}
    Failed to fetch record for 'hexpm/phoenix_pubsub' from registry (using cache)
{:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order}}]}
    Failed to fetch record for 'hexpm/postgrex' from registry (using cache)
{:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order}}]}
    Failed to fetch record for 'hexpm/ex_machina' from registry (using cache)
{:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order}}]}
    Failed to fetch record for 'hexpm/jason' from registry (using cache)
{:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'repo.hex.pm', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], {:option, :server_only, :honor_cipher_order}}]}
```

And so on for every dependency. What does `:no_honor_cipher` mean? Am I doing something wrong or is Hex down?

Comment: In case of this it's always best to check if your build environment can contact hex.pm. So, try `ping hex.pm` or `curl -L https://hex.pm`, and see what that tells you.

Comment: Try updating Hex with `mix local.hex` - `honor_cipher_order` is an option that the Erlang SSL client library has silently ignored until Erlang/OTP 22.1, so some libraries using it need updating.

Comment: I was getting this too. I still have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same error, for me the suggestion from @legoscia worked: update Hex with `mix local.hex`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's a bug in Hackney, that has been fixed in master, on Erlang 22.1, and in Hex shows up from version pinning problems... I'd make sure your `mix.exs` file has the correct (**newest**) versions of the dependencies it needs (like LiveView) or downgrade to a version of Erlang not 22.1 until your dependencies are updated.

This looks to be the root of the issue:

https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/issues/591